# How to skip $index in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Consider the following:

```
   <div ng-repeat='quest in quests'>
                        <div ng-switch on="quest.ui.type">
                            <div ng-switch-when="ms-select-single" >
                                <div ms-select-single quest='quest'
                                 quest-num='{{(true)?numInc():return}}'></div>
                            </div>
                            <div ng-switch-when="ms-select-multy">
                                <div ms-select-multy quest='quest'
                                quest-num='{{(true)?numInc():return}}'></div>
                            </div>
                            <div ng-switch-when="ms-date">
                                <div ms-date quest='quest'
                                 quest-num='{{(true)?numInc():return}}'>{{questNo}}</div>
                            </div>
                            <div ng-switch-when="ms-text">
                                <div ms-text quest='quest'
                                quest-num='{{(true)?numInc():return}}'>{{questNo}}</div>
                            </div>
                            <div ng-switch-when="ms-textarea">
                                <div ms-textarea quest='quest'
                                quest-num='{{(true)?numInc():return}}'>{{questNo}}</div>
                            </div>
                            <div ng-switch-when="ms-number">
                                <div ms-number quest='quest'
                                quest-num='{{(true)?numInc():return}}'>{{questNo}}</div>
                            </div>
                            <div ng-switch-when="ms-html">
                                <div ms-html quest='quest'></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

What should be my true statement in the  quest-num='{{(**true**)?numInc():return}}'>?

What i want to achieve is an increment a model value conditionaly when the statement is true, if it's true all the time the program breaks, what should be my true statement here?

numInc returns a ++ of a num value in the model, initialized first at 0, and when it hits the function it increments, but because i have ng-switch it increments too many times, that's why i need the true/false statement, i think...

Comment: What do you mean "What should be my true statement"? When should it be true? I think you could simplify what you have by simply using && instead, `(expression) && numInc()`, there's no need for the return statement in the false branch if you're not using it..

Comment: Ok but what that expression might be...

Comment: I'm not following. When should questNo increment, and when shouldn't it? Can't you simply use a property in your quest items, then you don't have to jump through hoops for incrementing a variable?

Comment: Alright, i have a json that returns quests items, some which should be counted as (question 1:.....question 2.....) now, there is some that i don't want to increment, that's why i dont use index anymore, but the problem is, with no expression just an increment function, the program breaks with too many digest...

Comment: Why don't you set the index when you received your json, then you have full control over the index and incrementation? What I mean is, you should separate logic that affects your items from the view and put it in your controller instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood your question but if you wanted something like this

```
     Label    Actual $index value
Question 1    0
              1
Question 2    2
Question 3    3
         etc...
```

Then we can use a directive. Here's a quick sketch

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainController', function($scope){
    $scope.arr = [{name:'John', phone:'555-1276'},
     {name:'Mary', phone:'800-BIG-MARY'},
     {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321', countMe:false},
     {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678'},
     {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765'},
     {name:'Juliette', phone:'555-5678', countMe:false}]
});

app.directive('conditionalNumberDirective', function(){
    var counter = 0;
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, el, attr) {
        // config what is item and what is coutMe via attrs here 
        if(scope.$index === 0) {
          counter = 1;
        }
        scope.counter = counter;
        if(angular.isDefined(scope.item) && angular.isDefined(scope.item.countMe) && !scope.item.countMe) {
          scope.counter = null;
        }else {
          counter++
        }
      }
    }
});
```

Html would look something like

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="search"/>
    <div ng-repeat="item in arr | filter:search"  conditional-number-directive>
  Index:{{$index}} {{item}} - Label:{{counter}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $index use a ng-model variable. You could try something like this also(ternary):

```
 {{ true ? true : false }}
```

while assigning the value.

Comment: When i did so, something like this:ng-init="questNo = (num+1), no incrementing is happening

Comment: <div ng-switch-when="ms-number">
                                <div ms-number quest='quest' quest-num='{{questNoInc()|questNo}}'>{{questNo}}</div> and the questNoInc is a function that return a ++ of the before, angular goes crazy digesting

Comment: Would you mind to further your answer with it's use on my example?