# Skipping items in ng-repeat (not ng-if)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way I could literally skip a given amount of items when iterating with `ng-repeat`?

For example, let's say I have this array:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Is there a way I could do something like

```
<div ng-repeat="i in arr">
    <div ng-if="i == 3" ng-skip="10">{{i}}</div></br>
</div>
```

So the output will be:

```
1
2
13
14
15
```

And the `ng-if` won't be executed for values from `3` to `12`.

Being clear here, what I'm asking is for some kind of modification is the iterator's behavior.

EDIT:

Let me clarify even further.

I'm asking for the equivalent of

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].should_skip_items == true) {
        i += arr[i].number_of_items_to_skip;
    } else {
        //do stuff...
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30243421/696034 will be the answer, I believe.

Comment: use a filter and pass the start position and the end position and dont return the data between this 2 positions

Comment: @nada That was just an example. I'll need to skip/seek multiple times.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov I believe that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Did u try with `ng-switch` and `ng-switch-when`?

Comment: @Shashank I can't see at all how `ng-switch` will work here. AFAIK `ng-switch` will swap DOM elements. I want to entirely skip elements with an iterator (not even create the DOM elements).

Comment: It gives an example of having a filter directive, so you may get an idea of returning true or false for each element, inserting check for it before  <div ng-if. Alternatively you may try using $index to check the index of the iteration as per https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: @DanielProtopopov That's the entire point. I don't want to process each element. I want to skip entire chunks of the array.

Comment: If your concern is just that you don't want the extra elements in the DOM, `ng-if` should be fine (as opposed to `ng-show`).  If you're trying to improve performance by not having the `ng-repeat` see the extra elements at all, then you need to preprocess your array; by the time it reaches `ng-repeat` it's already too late.

Comment: You ever figure this out?  I've got a similar issue-ish where I want to skip elements based on some predicate, but not increment $index on the skip.  ngIf works visually, but $index still increments so when it visually should be 3 it might be 5, etc

Comment: @mtpultz The only way is to previously filter the array, no other way, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$index` and `ngSwitch` as follows:

```
//skip one item
<div ng-repeat="i in arr" ng-switch="$index % 2 === 0">
    <div ng-switch-when="true">{{i}}</div></br>
</div>
```

So, what happens here is that if `$index % 2 === 0`, that is, the iterable is an even index, it will be shown.

Comment: As I said already in my reply to @Shashank , I believe this will still iterate over all elements in the array, but it will just hide the ones that don't match the condition. I want to entirely skip elements, as if I was doing a `seek` operation when reading a file in C.

Comment: I am not sure thats possible. You may want to pre-filter your array in the controller in that case.

Comment: Likely there is no such control over internal iterator that's hidden in the AngularJS' logic. It provides extensions like directives, but I frankly don't see how to achieve the result besides doing work on the array prior to passing it to ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
  ng-repeat="i in arr track by $index" ng-if="$index < 2 || $index > 11"
```

and remove `ng-if` and `ng-switch` from inner DIV element.

Comment: This will work only for one-time skip operations. I need to do multiple skips (and also I don't know at what index I'll have to skip and how many items I'll have to skip)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

`ng-if="arr.slice(arr.indexOf(3), arr.indexOf(3)+10).indexOf(i) === -1"`

Comment: Please see my answer to @Nimesh

Comment: No, it's still exactly the same. That won't let me skip more than once.